# Rails - Add Column Name That Is An Array Of Date Ranges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For my final project in my Intro To Ruby on Rails class, I have to make an e-commerce website. However, I decided to go more advanced than the scope of the class, so instead of the quantity of a service, I want that service to have an array of Date appointments.

For example, if this is a massage service, I need each massage service to have "appointment" attributes so the user can know the following:

"This massage service has the several open appointment ranges:

03/21/2016 from 3:00pm to 5:00pm

03/22/2016 from 2:00pm to 4:00pm

03/23/2016 from 12:00pm to 2:00pm"

How would I get this done?

Comment: A `MassageService` `has_many :appointments`.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up just making an "Appointment" data table so each appointment will have the massage_service_id. Think I'm starting to get a hang of this rails database stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association

Let me know if you have any questions on how to implement it